# Regex - json fetch

Tags: php, json, regex

I tried to learn regular expressions but it's hard to learn it fast and I have a problem. I display in laravel some kind of message which look like this:

> B0679/17 NOTAMN Q) EPWW/QFALC/IV/NBO/A /000/999/5133N02154E005 A) EPDE B) 1701241325 C) 1701242100 E) AD CLSD FOR LDG AND TKOF DUE TO ICE ON RWY,TWY AND APRON.

It's inline and and now I want to display it in format like this:

```
Q) EPWW/QFALC/IV/NBO/A /000/999/5133N02154E005 
A) EPDE 
B) 1701241325
C) 1701242100
E) AD CLSD FOR LDG AND TKOF DUE TO ICE ON RWY,TWY AND APRON.
```

For now my PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

$url = "http://api.vateud.net/notams/EPDE.json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$obj= json_decode($json);

foreach($obj as $o=>$key){

    echo $key->raw . '<br />' ;
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: i want to display each part A) B) C) under each so A) under A B) under B C). Now it displays me inline

Comment: can be as array

Comment: how does your json look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, looking at the data I see it already has carriage returns in it. Of course, these won't show in HTML, so just use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.vateud.net/notams/EPDE.json"));
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    echo nl2br($obj->raw);
}
```

Another option is to use a `<pre>` element, which keeps the monospaced font that users of this data might be used to. This will print out the carriage returns already in the data:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.vateud.net/notams/EPDE.json"));
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($obj->raw) . "</pre>";
}
```

My original regular expression answer:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.vateud.net/notams/EPDE.json"));
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]+\))/", "\n$1", $obj->raw) . "<br/>\n";
}
```

In either case, ditch the complicated curl nonsense and just use `file_get_contents()`!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to add some linebreaks in front of every `A)`, etc. You can use the following regular expression to find every occurrence:

```
[A-Z]\).*?(?=[A-Z]\)|$)
```

- `[A-Z]` → matches every capital letter from `A` to `Z`
- `\)` → matches a `)` character, escaped notation
- `.*?` → matches any character 0 or more times (but as few as possible)
- `(?=)` → positive lookahead for a sequence (must be there after the previous selector)
- `[A-Z]\)|$` → matches either any large letter followed by a `)` or the end of the string

---

**Here is an example in JavaScript:**

```js
var text = "B0679/17 NOTAMN Q) EPWW/QFALC/IV/NBO/A /000/999/5133N02154E005 A) EPDE B) 1701241325 C) 1701242100 E) AD CLSD FOR LDG AND TKOF DUE TO ICE ON RWY,TWY AND APRON.";
var regex = /[A-Z]\).*?(?=[A-Z]\)|$)/g;

console.log(text.match(regex));
```